# Rails.3.1.1: config.assets.digest = true results in compiled css being used as a sprite's filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, css-sprites, asset-pipeline, compass-sass

I have a new-ish rails 3.1.1 app using sass/compass with compass taking care of the sprite generations for me. In development, all works just fine. However, when I deploy, I see this entry in the log file:

```
Compiled team/application.css  (1ms)  (pid 24202)
Compiled team/forms.css  (0ms)  (pid 24202)
Compiled team/member.css  (0ms)  (pid 24202)
Compiled application.css  (0ms)  (pid 24202)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2014ms

ActionView::Template::Error (File name too long - /home/cri/webapps-releases/cri/releases/20111121225403/app/assets/images/html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote...(the rest of my compiled css goes here)
```

My production config (for asset stuff) is pretty vanilla wiht much of it being what was generated by rails:

```
  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Specify the default JavaScript compressor
  config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  config.assets.debug = true
```

Can anybody tell me why my compiled css is being used as the filename for the sprite?

Update: Modified title to reflect what I now think I know about this issue.

I am running rails-3.1.1 with sass-3.1.10 and sass-rails-3.1.5 and compass-0.11.3.

Comment: If I set config.assets.digest = false, then the problem goes away. So, the question now becomes who should I file this bug to?

Comment: have you precompiled your assets? Do you know about the `.css.sass` extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

compass-0.11.3 does not have proper asset pipeline support you are going to want to be using the >= 0.12.alpha.3 release you can get this by doing `gem install compass --pre` if you are still having this issue under 0.12 then it is a bug and i would be grateful if you would file a ticket on the compass github.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Those workarounds are true, but [this bug in rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3333) was fixed in 3.1.4. Upgrading is likely your best all-around bet.